# Image above Navigation Drawer (using fragments)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

There were a lot of questions similar to this but none of them hasn't explained this situation:

I've created app from Android Studio's templates. App is with `Navigation Drawer` but, not like everybody else, it uses fragments to cast it. I want to add `ImaveView` above `ListView` but I get following error: 
`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams`

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:src="@drawable/image">
        </ImageView>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="tuksiarz.app.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </LinearLayout>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_navigation_drawer.xml

```
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#f7f9f6"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

NavigationDrawerFragment.java

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";


private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerListView;
private View mFragmentContainerView;

private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String[] mCategories = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_categories);

    ImageView logo = new ImageView(getActivity());
    logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ciechanow);
    logo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);


    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            android.R.id.text1,
            mCategories));

    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });

    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}

public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
    return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
}


public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivity(),                    
            mDrawerLayout,                    
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,             
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {

                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).commit();
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerListView != null) {
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}

private ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}


public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
}
}
```

It it necessary to add MainActivity.java? I don't want to spam too much code.

Comment: have u tried using widths as 380 dp instead of @dimen/navigation_drawer_width

Comment: It made no difference

Comment: Plz add the fullstack trace and important piece of code of the main activity (like onCreate). Consider setting the height of the image view and the fragment to 0dp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arent u supposed to close the drawer layout here :

```
 mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
```

Create an object of linear layout that contains items of navigation drawer (image and fragment in ur case) and do something like this :

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(linearlayout);
```

Comment: Thank you Hirak very much! :)

Comment: m glad i could help. happy programming